# I wish To show random Text in my splash screen's text view using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I'm trying to Show a random text from an array[ using kotlin ] in my splash screen [ before the MainActivity starts i suppose,] i tried ,

```
val thoughts = arrayOf("Trading Made Easy!","Where Smart People Trade","For Smart Traders Like You!")
    fun getRandomQuote(): String {
        val randomValue = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(thoughts.size)
        return thoughts[randomValue]
    }
    var thought = getRandomQuote().toString()
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rand)
    textView.setText(thought)
```

But this Makes The App Close automatically instead of showing the splash screen. this line --> textView.setText(thought) has some problem because when i remove that line, the app doesn't crash and the above Function Returns a string ( i tested it with toast )
Anyway To Solve It? Or Any Other Alternate Way?

Comment: If you're crashing, post the stack trace from the log.  It will tell you the reason why you crashed.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n5g5ZeRE this is my log cat report for my package

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of using thoughts.size,  you should use thoughts.size-1
```

otherwise you
might get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while using
thoughts[randomValue]
fun getRandomQuote(): String {
val randomValue =
kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(thoughts.size)
return thoughts[randomValue]
}

Comment: I did it, But It Crashes again

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
before trying to set the `Textview` solved the problem.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}
```